# routing between LXC containers in deferent subnets

Tags: networking, lxc, routing, container

I have 2 containers in deferent subnets, one 10.1.1.1/24 and 10.1.2.1/24. I want to connect them together, how can i do it ?

Comment: are they running on the same host ?

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, yes they are. and maybe in future i want to add more container with other subnets. thanks

Comment: any reason that they connecte into different subnets ? what did you do for trouble-shooting already ?

Comment: i didn't do any troubleshooting.

Comment: hi, anybody can help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

if they run on the same host you should take care that you can ping the ip-addresses set for your containers. make sure no firewall on the host is block anything. read here for more details about LXC networking: https://wiki.debian.org/LXC/SimpleBridge